# Add LOCAL folder to IMAP store

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I need to create folder in IMAP store. That folder needs to be a Local folder. 
When I call this code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= inboxFolder.Parent.Folders.Count; i++)
{
    Log.Debug((RDOFolder2)inboxFolder.Parent.Folders[i]).FolderPath);
}
```

I get output below.

```
...
\\someone@somedomain\Deleted Items
\\someone@somedomain\Inbox
\\someone@somedomain\Outbox
\\someone@somedomain\Sent Items
\\someone@somedomain\Sync Issues (This computer only)
...
```

You see how "Sync Issues" folder has "(This computer only)". Thats the kind of folder I need in my IMAP store.

If I create folder of type rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox with RDOFolders.Add method, it is deleted which is probably expected. So what I need is:

```
...
\\someone@somedomain\MyOwnFolder (This computer only)
\\someone@somedomain\Deleted Items
\\someone@somedomain\Inbox
\\someone@somedomain\Outbox
\\someone@somedomain\Sent Items
\\someone@somedomain\Sync Issues (This computer only)
...
```

I need it to be olFolderInbox type.

I asked question using redemption code but Outlook.Folders.Add signature looks same to me. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: I found out that folder is not deleted but it is moved under Inbox folder. Looks insane especially because ROOT folder is not set to inbox its empty. I am experimenting with it I hope I will find something.

Comment: Just a detail more. If you "root" your IMAP account (advanced account settings under outlook) and put Inbox in root directory field then outlook recognizes folder structure properly and it doesn't have a problem with moving folders you create to inbox.